# GroupBy with count on two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Please ignore if its very basic question as i am not good in SQL and have to develop query i google and couldnt get my desired result.

I have two tables

Product

```
ProductID, ProductName, Descritpion
  2010        A           xyz
  2011        B           uyt
  2012        C           jkj
```

And Sales like below

```
Sales
SalesID, ProductID,     SaleDate,      Status
  1        2010        10-Dec-2013       K
  2        2010        10-Dec-2013       u
  3        2011        11-Dec-2013       i
```

I have to develop a query which will return count of daily sales like following

```
ProductName, TotalSaleCount, SaleDate
    A               2         10-Dec-2013
```

I develop following query

```
SELECT productid, 
       Count(1) 
FROM   sales 
WHERE  saledate = Trunc(sysdate - 1) 
GROUP  BY productid
```

Above query return productid with count but i want productname with count so how i will join sales table with product?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different answer than the existing ones;

```
SELECT Product.ProductName, TotalSales.TotalSaleCount, TotalSales.SaleDate
FROM Product
JOIN (SELECT ProductId, SaleDate, COUNT(*) as TotalSaleCount
      FROM Sales
      GROUP BY ProductId, SaleDate) TotalSales
  ON TotalSales.ProductId = Product.id
```

The results should be identical to some of the existing answers.
**However**, this version is *likely* (but not guaranteed) to be faster - the columns chosen are more likely to have indices on them, and to be better choices for indices, too; `ProductName` is usually *not* a good column to put as the start of this type of index, and (depends on how smart the optimizer actually is), as it's not part of `Sales`, is less useful to the optimizer.

Comment: I tried it but result is not much improved, what is i replace following line ON TotalSales.ProductId = Productid  with using(Productid)

Comment: I hope that was `Product_dot_Id` in the join, or it's going to be a cross join, which isn't what you want.  `USING(...)` is really just syntactic sugar for a regular join, there's no reason why it should be an improvement.  It's also MySQL-specific, I believe, and should be avoided in favor of the standard `ON` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Just join on the `Product` table:

```
SELECT   productname, COUNT(*) 
FROM     Sales 
JOIN     Product ON Sales.productid = Product.producyid
WHERE    saledate = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
GROUP BY ProductName
```

Comment: in group by i mention sales.productid or product.product.id? as it throw following error ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: The `GROUP BY` list should correspond to the `SELECT` list. It was supposed to be `GROUP BY ProductName`. I fixed my answer, thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.PRODUCTNAME,count(t1.PRODUCTNAME) as TotalSaleCount,t2.SALEDATE from Product t1 , Sales t2 
where t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID AND saledate = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
GROUP BY t2.SALEDATE,t1.PRODUCTNAME;
```